# Bands similar to Pink Floyd

Tags: similar-artists, pink-floyd

"Echoes" by Pink floyd is the best song I've ever heard, all my life I never really have listened to Pink Floyd. I'm not even a stoner, I just like the deepness some of their songs.

I've always listened to Rush or The Offspring or the Foo Fighters. Pink floyd is a sound which is completely different. I've always thought Pink Floyd made really depressing songs and I didn't like that. But now that I am older, they are actually quite deep and calming to listen to while doing work.

**Question: Can someone suggest something similar to "Echoes"? Or a band similar to Pink Floyd?**

Comment: Checkout the band named, MGMT

Comment: Camel is very similar as well...

Comment: https://www.music-map.com/pink+floyd.html

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_rock)

Comment: Maybe not quite a dupe, but linked - https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5887/modern-bands-like-pink-floyd-yes-genesis-transatlantic

Comment: this guy has a good collection of what you asked: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOrxzF3UctI

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for songs similar to Echoes:

**Pink Floyd** (Indeed one of the greatest bands of all time;  certainly a favorite of mine after The Beatles)

- Shine On You Crazy Diamond [Parts I-IX] from *Wish You Were Here* (More than 25 minutes of pure, absolute genius)
- Sheep from *Animals* is not as haunting and calm as Echoes, but it is certainly a thrill. (10 more minutes of greatness)
- Us and Them from *The Dark Side of the Moon* (A very calm song if that is what you are looking for)

**King Crimson**

- Epitaph from *In the Court of the Crimson King* (Amazing song from an extraordinary album. King Crimson pioneered progressive rock in '69 when Pink Floyd were more psychedelic)

*Similar* bands to **Pink Floyd**:

- **Yes:** They have a different approach to progressive rock, but they are great as well with amazing albums such as *Fragile* and *Close to the Edge*.
- **Emerson, Lake, and Palmer:** A superb progressive rock trio, check out their *Trilogy* album.

*Keep in mind that most progressive rock band members changed constantly, so some albums are slightly different. This is mostly the case of King Crimson, whick rocked its first album, but almost everybody except the lead guitar left afterwards, and they did not have a commmercial hit until their fourth album, *Red*, with another shift in personnel.*

Comment: You really forgot about Genesis )))

Answer (score 3):

The best that come to mind are: Asia, Transatlantic, Yogi Lang, Yes, Genesis, Camel, RPWL, Jon Lord - Before I Forget, King Crimson, Eloy (maybe) and Emerson; Lake and Palmer.

Answer (score 3):

What you have discovered is love for golden age progressive rock, when songs were not just calm and mesmerizing, but the lyrics were also deep, meaningful and they were complemented by extraordinary music!

Not many people appreciate such beautiful music nowadays, so good to see such love for one of my favourite bands.

Some similar bands/artists and their songs you may like are:

- **Porcupine Tree** - Russia on Ice, Trains, Arriving somewhere but not here. A good progressive band from the relatively recent times (the 90s).
- **The Doors** - When the music's over, Hello I love you, Riders on the storm, Light my fire, L.A. woman, The Ghost Song. Psychedelic music at it's best.
- **The Who** - Won't get fooled again, Baba O' Riley, Who are you, Behind blue eyes.
- **Oasis** - Champagne supernova, Wonderwall, Don't look back in anger.
- **Dire Straits** - Brothers in arms.

Other long, deep progressive songs you might like:

- Dogs, Shine on you crazy diamond (all parts, don't listen to them separately, it's a 26 minute masterpiece), by **Pink Floyd**.
- In the court of the Crimson King, Starless, by **King Crimson**.
- Firth of Fifth, by **Genesis**.

Listen to any Pink Floyd songs from the Syd Barret era (their earlier works were more psychedelic owing to Syd's contributions), you might like them.
If you like listening to guitar (you just might), try something from Steve Vai or Joe Satriani.
Keep discovering great music, cheers.

Comment: Add to Porcupine Tree; Steven Wilson's solo work - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Wilson

Comment: look at this https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0FrQIyqrrfOFPll7R5JRtw

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people will say, "Oh.  Pink Floyd.  OK, here's a bunch of Prog Rock bands."  And they're kinda wrong.  Pink Floyd was not like Yes or Genesis or ELP, because Pink Floyd were really more (**much** more) of a Blues-based band.  And as much as I love the genre and the bands in it, there really wasn't another band similar to Pink Floyd in that genre.  Not too many Prog bands really grooved like Floyd.

Echoes, in particular, was probably more similar to the live versions of Stairway To Heaven (Feb 14, 1975 comes to mind), especially the solo section.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJxpOZ6XIZ4

If you're going to compare it to Yes, I'd say maybe Ritual is somewhat similar; although the frenetic sections are much more frenetic, the mellower sections have somewhat of a bluesy feel to them.  But, again, Yes couldn't swing if they were sitting in a hammock.  The music is there, the groove is not.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJzzBUKTFQQ

Comment: You nailed it with the blues comment!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to "Echoes" in terms of length  and my personal suggestion is `Shine on you crazy diamond` a nine-part Pink Floyd composition:

Here is the full length (part i-ix) video:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuBqE9xGtiQ

Here is something i just found: [Similar tracks to Pink Floyd "Echoes"](https://ourwalrus.com/music/similartracks/Pink+Floyd/Echoes%2C+Parts+1+%26+2)

Answer (score 1):

**Direct Answer To Your Question**:--

Porcupine Tree, Riverside, and Anathema are relatively mainstream bands that are very similar to Pink Floyd.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3lsqUqGTzM)

Don't underestimate David Gilmour's solo career.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtsG5eAZj0c)

---

**Notable but Forgotten Bands**:--

More obscure bands or artists that deal with in psychedelia are: maudlin of the Well and Leigh Stephens' solo career. The band, mauldin of the Well, is notable for having songs inspired by lucid dreaming and similar practices.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13cBXtwvsYo)

The 13th Floor Elevators is another obscure band that is important in the development of psychedelic rock.

---

**Other References**:--

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_rock)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychedelic_rock)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer sound of Pink Floyd after 1980, then check out band **Tony Red** and their only one album **Positive Waves**. Also I will recommend to check out bands **Mostly Autumn**, **Moon Halo** and also band **Cosmos**, they have five albums from 1995 till 2012. There is another band you should pay attention, it is **Think Floyd**.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out Porcupine Tree. Especially their earlier stuff such as the albums the sky moves sideways or signify. Basically anything by them from the 90's but especially those two from that time period. The few albums that are a bit later are good too but at some point they started to get a bit more metal(starting with In Absentia which is still great but leaning towards a heavier sound on some tracks).

I also recommend these bands for the Floyd sound. Eloy(their mid to late 70's albums in particular such as silent cries and might echoes have a very Floyd vibe and were obviously influenced by WYWH. Some long tracks on those albums. Also, the bands Nektar, RPWL, Camel and Airbag.

There are plenty more. Go to progarchives and do a search for bands similar to Pink Floyd. As was mentioned you will mostly find what you are looking for in the progressive rock genre but there are some newer indie and post rock bands who are influenced by PF also.

Answer (score 0):

There are also new bands that have pink floyd influences like the Porcupine Tree, Marillion, Ayeron, The Tangent, Steve Thorne, Steven Wilson's solo band and Kino!

Comment: Hi! Maybe a few links, references and more details would be great to expand your answer. List-only answers are not recommended in SE format.

Answer (score 0):

Try the band Stonesfield.  Their album 'Your Dream Alone' is free on Spotify and on Youtube here:  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcG8wKBUWKGAtzvR6Jc6KtQ

Answer (score 0):

[Radiohead's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiohead) [OK Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK_Computer) made a lot of noise about being close to the Pink Floyd sound when it came out, especially the song '[Lucky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_(Radiohead_song))'.