# Modern bands like Pink Floyd, Yes, Genesis, Transatlantic?

Tags: bands

What modern or very new bands can you advise me to listen to that play music resembling Pink Floyd, Genesis, Yes, or Transatlantic?

Comment: Check out "Scenes from the Box" ("Scenes from the Box - Topic" on Youtube)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ought to have a listen to [Steven Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Wilson), solo albums, work with Porcupine Tree & collaborations with some of the names on your list.

He's pretty much regarded as **the** 'modern prog guy' - though across various albums he sways from almost jazz to almost metal, so he's not that easy to tie down.

His catalogue is too large to really know where to start - however, the first album of his I heard was [Hand.Cannot.Erase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Wilson#Hand._Cannot._Erase.) which prompted me to find other of his material; so why not start from there...

A bit of biog from Wikipedia...

> Currently a solo artist, he became known as the founder, lead
> guitarist, singer, and songwriter of the band Porcupine Tree, as well
> as being a member of several other bands. He has also worked with
> artists such as Opeth, King Crimson, Pendulum, Jethro Tull, XTC, Yes,
> Marillion, Tears for Fears, Roxy Music, and Anathema.
>
> Wilson is a self-taught producer, audio engineer, guitar and keyboard
> player, playing other instruments as needed, including bass guitar,
> autoharp, hammered dulcimer and flute. Despite being mainly associated
> with prog music, his influences and work have encompassed diverse
> genres such as psychedelia, pop, extreme metal, electronic, and jazz,
> among others, shifting his musical direction through his albums.
> His concerts incorporate quadraphonic sound and elaborate visuals.
>
> In a career spanning more than 30 years, Wilson has made music
> prolifically and earned critical acclaim. His honours include four
> nominations for the Grammy Awards, twice with Porcupine Tree, with his
> collaborative band Storm Corrosion and as a soloist on one occasion.
> In 2015, he received three awards at the London Progressive Music
> Awards for his services to the world of progressive rock music and
> crowned "the king of prog rock". Nevertheless, his work has largely
> stayed away from mainstream music, being described by publications
> such as The Daily Telegraph as "the most successful British artist
> you’ve never heard of."

Comment: I've uncovered Yogi Lang who is very close to Pink Floyd.

Comment: I've also revealed the Manfred Mann's Earth Band is really close to Pink Floyd, and from my point of view the band Asia is great too and very close to their style.

Answer (score 4):

A few bands that I have discovered recently that are reminiscent of the bands you mentioned:

- The Physics House Band (Instrumental)
- Oceansize
- Amplifier
- Opeth (Their later albums are pure Prog Rock, their earlier material is much heavier, closer to Death Metal)
- Chon (Instrumental)
- From Monuments to Masses
- Vessels

Note that a lot of what gets labeled Post-Rock doesn't really sound that much different than 70s Prog Rock - so you can look up that genre for Pink Floyd / Yes style sounds.

Comment: Impressive list. I wonder if they are as good as Pink Floyd. Aa for me, PF is the best band.

Comment: @SovereignSun they're all good. The Physics House band would be the perfect heirs to PF, except that they don't have any lyrics.

Comment: I love instrumental music. If they are at least no worth than PF - The Endless River album then I'm already their fan.

Comment: @SovereignSun https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxOcmvP8vZY

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have enough reputation to comment, I will tack on some relevant info here as an answer.

I second the Steven Wilson recommendation. However, I think it's worth noting that in terms of sound, you're more likely to get what you're after with his solo work. Further, his solo stuff seems to encapsulate single themes (like alienation in the modern world or whatever) more broadly and thoroughly, whilst Porcupine Tree albums have more of a 'concept album' feel. Hope that helps!

P.S. the band Tool might also be worth a listen, though they only really seem similar to Pink Floyd, and last released an album in 2006.

Comment: **Tool** is pretty old. I listened to them several years ago. I wouldn't ever call them modern or a new band.

Answer (score 2):

All your example bands can be listed under the category of 'prog (progressive) rock'.  Although a tautology, searching 'modern prog rock' may guide you to some answers.

Examples from this '[music afficionado](https://web.musicaficionado.com/main.html#!/article/the_ten_best_bands_in_modern_prog_rock_by_jimfarber)' page, for instance includes suggestions like: Syd Arthur, Suuns, Battles, while this [reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/comments/1gsyeg/best_modernprogressive_rockmetal_bands/) points to the abovementioned Steven Wilson as well as Astra, Mostly Autumn, etc.

Comment: I'll have a look at those. However, unfortunately, most of what I google up and eventually find is really not good. The sound is mostly very poor, the solos are cheap and untidy, the harnony is rediculous, the vocals are disgusting. I would really like something as good as those bands I've mentioned. I listened to **Jon Lord's - Before I forget** some few years ago and that's what I call something as good as Pink Floyd.

Answer (score 2):

This question makes me feel really old because normally I would consider "Transatlantic" modern but the thing is their first album came out seventeen years ago. "Porcupine Tree" were around back then too though. Steven Wilson is the obvious answer(and PT too)but there are tons of other bands and artists. I suggest going to progarchives and doing a search or buy PROG magazine. Other than that "Big Big Train" is often considered to be one of the very best of the newer bands. You might want to also check out "Spock's Beard", "Anglagard", "IQ" and "The Flower Kings" even though they have all been around a while but they have that classic prog sound which fans of the older bands would quite possibly like.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Transatlantic is modern so in a way you answered your own question. Also check out the Flower Kings, IQ, Spock's Beard and Glass Hammer to name just a few more post seventies modern prog. All good stuff but there's plenty more. Go to progarchives.com for many more(older and newer).

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  So nobody is ever going to be as great as Pink Floyd.  But here's an album by a band that might fill the gap they have left...
'Your Dream Alone' by Stonesfield.  Here's a Youtube link.  Also available on Spotify.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAS7eH8snjU&list=OLAK5uy_kesAAhu8zLAf3vSYgQYSPfg3iKYEVw00c

Answer (score 1):

Check out the band Pfilbryte album  The Bell
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=pfilbryte+the+bell

Answer (score 1):

No specific bands to offer (I think other answers cover that well).

However, try this website if you want to find 'bands like others bands'

https://www.music-map.com/